# Click event for Stacked Area Chart in C3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, c3.js

I have a stacked area chart and i need each area should be clickable and based on the area clicked data1/data2/data3 respective route will be done.

If I set data.selection.grouped = true, I am able to click on the whole area but the click event is getting triggered for all data(data1, data2 and data3).

If I set data.selection.grouped = false, Click is available only on the data point, but I need the whole area should be clickable.

Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: I want this as well. Unfortunately, the areas of Area Charts are defined as big polygons with the line defined by the data as one side.

I think if we want this, we need to be able to identify the coordinates inside the chart where we're clicking, and then figure out the four surrounding points.